# Record sound from a single aplication

Tags: windows-7, audio, recording

I need to be able to record the sound from a single application (in this case minecraft) without the recording containing any other sounds from other applications.

I cannot just mute the applications as I need to be able to hear them whilst recording.

Is there any way of me doing this?

I'm running 64-bit Windows 7 if it matters.

The reason I'm asking this is that Windows has the capability of controlling application sound separately, so I figure it must be possible to record them in the same way.

[image: Windows volume mixer]

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a "sound server" or an "audio server", such as [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/) or [PulseAudio](http://www.pulseaudio.org/) (if it works on Windows 7). Their whole point is to redirect audio streams between applications (e.g. redirect audio output from Minecraft into some recording software). But I'm not sure how to actually use them for this, which is why I'm not posting an answer.

Comment: @Oak PulseAudio is Unix only, and JACK seems to treat all application sounds as a single channel, apart from certain applications designed to be able to be routed. (Minecraft not being one of them)

Comment: Minecraft has a tendency to be dicey for certain issues on account of it being a Java program.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to use Virtual Audio Cable to route the audio feeds.

Examples of how to use it are in this "How to Produce a Live Audio Podcast" post:

http://www.barnesian.com/2011/10/how-to-produce-live-audio-podcast.html