# Duplicate sound playback device

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, playback

I was going to play a game with friends using TeamSpeak. I wanted to seperate our voices from the actual game, yet still hear both in my headphones.

I suppose it would be possible to somehow duplicate the playback device of my headphone and redirect the voice to the copy and record the sound on the default playback device. But how does one achieve this?

As a last resort I could always choose to play-back my friends voices on my monitor's speakers. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/396491/record-sound-from-a-single-aplication) on SuperUser helped me out.

In a nutshell: a program called Virtual Audio Cable allows you to create additional virtual playback and recording devices.

In my setup, I set Virtual Audio Cable's *Line 1* as the default playback device and ticked its associated *recording device*'s *Listen* option. Then I set its *listening target* to my actual playback device, i.e. my speakers. *TeamSpeak*, *Skype*, and/or any other voice chatting application must now be manually set to use the actual playback device if supported.

Unfortunately the program comes with a relatively small fee.